# Replace a character in a string using assembly code in MASM

Tags: string, assembly, replace, character, masm

So my program is very simple. I have a string "Hello World" and I want to replace 'H' with 'A'. So here is my assembly code for MASM.

```
char* name = "Hello World";
_asm
{
mov eax, name;
mov ebx, 'A';
mov [eax], ebx;
}

printf("%s", name);
```

Visual Studio cannot compile this. It alerts me that this program is not working. I suspect my syntax for mov[eax], ebx might be wrong. All comments are appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the image of the alert: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5ok96pj0mxi6sa/test%20program%20not%20working.PNG

Comment: _Exactly_ what is the error message you get? (copy-paste it verbatim into your question)

Comment: @Michael just put an image link to the question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Michael with  'move eax, OFFSET name', I got error C2415: improper operand type. With 'lea eax, [name]', I got some weird output: "CaC". I changed the second line to mov bl, 'A'. And third line to mov [eax], bl

Comment: Here are the images of the updated program: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqssvqqwz6vnqps/test%20program%20not%20working%202.PNG

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0rwzhpn8phbb3c8/test%20program%20not%20working%203.PNG

Comment: You must preserve the value of `ebx` so that its value is the same after your code as it was before. One way of doing that is to issue a `push ebx` as the first instruction and a `pop ebx` as the last.

Comment: I'm guessing access violation while attempting to write a read-only segment.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError hm nope, ebx is not affecting my program. But thanks.

Comment: @MartinJames yeah i'm thinking the same. But I checked around and read a lot of info on the web. Everyone says mov [register], register should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hello World" is a literal, i.e a non-writeable constant string. 'name' is a pointer which points to that literal. You can instead define an array, which has to be populated with that literal, i.e. the literal is copied into the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char name[] = "Hello World";
    _asm
    {
        lea eax, name;    // EAX = address of name
        mov ebx, 'A';
        mov [eax], bl;
    }

    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}
```

The original code works, if you use the C89-Compiler of MSVC (file-extension `.c` or command line option `/TC`), but that does not really meet the standard.

Comment: So I changed char* to char []. The code works fine. And you're right. I can't change the literal. So another way I'm thinking is to work around char*. I create a char* name, copy the string to a char name2[], change a character in there. And then let name points to the new name2. It works. :D

Comment: oh but I have a new problem. I printf("%s", name) only prints out "A"

Comment: @Jon: `mov [eax], bl`! **Not** `mov [eax], ebx`! You want to store only one character (= one byte).

Answer (score 1):

First Character

```
    mov eax, _name;    // EAX = address of name
    mov bl, 'A';
    mov byte[eax], bl;
```

Second Character

```
mov eax, _name;    // EAX = address of name
mov bl, 'A';
mov byte[eax+1], bl;
```

MOVS

MOVS - This instruction moves 1 Byte, Word or Doubleword of data from memory location to another.

```
LODS
```

LODS - This instruction loads from memory. If the operand is of one byte, it is loaded into the AL register, if the operand is one word, it is loaded into the AX register and a doubleword is loaded into the EAX register.

```
STOS
```

STOS - This instruction stores data from register (AL, AX, or EAX) to memory.

```
CMPS
```

CMPS - This instruction compares two data items in memory. Data could be of a byte size, word or doubleword.

```
SCAS
```

SCAS - This instruction compares the contents of a register (AL, AX or EAX) with the contents of an item in memory.